# Filenotfound in external context as a resource

Tags: java, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

Following is my env: eclipse, tomcat, mercurial, jsf on the front end.

I recently renamed my welcome file from 'Welcome.xhtml' to 'welcome.xhtml'

I committed the changes,deployed to test and everything worked fine.

Then I pulled the changes into production. When I accessed the URL in production https://site.comp.com, a request was sent out for https://site.comp.com/app/Welcome.xhtml and then I got 500 error and filenotfound exception saying /Welcome.xhtml not found in externalcontext as a resource.

I tried clearing mercurial cache, tomcat cache, deleting the webapp and creating a new one thinking something somewhere is caching the old file, but I couldn't find anything. Any idea why such different behaviors in test and production?

Comment: If your file is named welcome.xhtml, why do you send a request to Welcome.xhtml, and why do you expect it to not cause an error?

Comment: Insufficient information. Show the web.xml extract. Did you delete Welcome.xhtml when you tested?

Comment: @ejp, file was renamed not deleted. So it was renamed from Welcome.xhtml to welcome.xhtml. I will web.xml extract to the question.